# Vue 3 / Typescript: "Cannot find name" in template variable

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

In Vue 3 / Typescript, I am getting the following error:

"Cannot find name", when referencing a data variable into the ... area.

How can I solve this?

Please see the attached screenshot.

[image]

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello ! I have the same problem, you found a solution?

Comment: Are you using Volar or Vetur?

Comment: For me this bug was caused by using two components inside each other. This kind of circular reference is possible in Vue via asynchronous imports, but `vue-tsc` doesn't seem to like it. The only way we managed to resolve it was by refactoring the codebase to remove circular dependencies. Note that I'm using Vue 3's composition API.

Comment: @JakeBrowning I'm having the same issue with the composition API. Every template ref throws an error. But I can't spot anywhere with a circular dependency. You said it  was caused by using two components inside each other.  What do you mean?

Comment: @Philx94 I mean there was a circular dependency where Vue component A was rendering Vue component B and vice versa. There could also be some other bug in `vue-tsc` which causes these errors.

Comment: Alright that's what I thought. My problem was coming from `vue-tsc` being outdated. Which really stinks since without changing anything to our `package.json` we could not deploy anymore.

Comment: In my case, It was resolved by opening the root project directory in VSCode. I mean, not nested directories.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue when I added lang="ts" to the vue file as I'm new to Vue 3 and Typescript. I resolved it by ensuring the following:

```
export default
```

to

```
export default defineComponent({
```

in your .vue file.

Ensure you add the import.

```
import { defineComponent }
```

Your data should reside in the setup as well.

```
setup () {
  return {
    loader: false,
    error: false,
    firstTime: false
```

Comment: The app is using the Options API and not the Composition API and it cannot upgraded/changed to the Composition API at the moment.


`export default defineComponent({`

is there already.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same bug, the code inference error, that was caused by the code **loop reference**.

I create a route-array-contant `in route.ts`, such as the following:

```
import { RouteRecordRaw, createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";

import Layout from "../layout/index";

export const NaviHeaderRoutes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: "/foo",
    name: "FOO",
    redirect: "/foo/index",
    component: Layout,
    children: [
      {
        path: "index",
        name: "foolIndex",
        component: () => import("../views/foo/index")
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "/bar",
    name: "BAR",
    redirect: "/bar/index",
    component: Layout,
    children: [
      {
        path: "index",
        name: "barIndex",
        component: () => import("../views/bar/index")
      }
    ]
  }
];

const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  ...NaviHeaderRoutes
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
});

export default router;
```

then I use `NaviHeaderRoutes` in the child component of `Layout.vue`

```
// layout.vue
<template>
  <NaviHeader></NaviHeader>
    <!-- error TS2304 cannot find name  in template variable -->
    <main :class="testClass">
      <RouterView />
    </main>
</template>
<sciprt lang="ts" setup>
const testClass = ref();
</script>
```

```
// naviheader
<template>
 <header>
 <!--error TS2304 cannot find name  in template variable-->
 <span>{{title}}</span>
 <span v-for="(hitem in NaviHeaderRoutes)" :key="hitem.name">
    <router-link :to="hitem.path">{{hitem.name}}</route-link>
 </span>
 <!--error TS2304 cannot find name  in template variable-->
 <div>{{username}}</div>
</header>
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
import {NaviHeaderRoutes} from '@/router'
const title = ref('')
const username = ref('')
</script>
```

Fix it is simple, try to set `route`'s component lately

```
export const NaviHeaderRoutes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: "/foo",
    name: "FOO",
    redirect: "/foo/index",
    // component: Layout,
// ....
]

const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  ...NaviHeaderRoutes.map((x) => {
    x.component = Layout;
    return x;
  })
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have this bug, but, I also had this. I have fix it by fixing a silent TS bug.
When I have fix this bug, everything was working again.

EDIT: I found the bug I had. I had put an enum in a *.d.ts file and I was using this enum in the file that gave me the same error as you. The problem is that an enum can't be in a *.d.ts file because it is not compiled in JS afterwards and you lose the enum's value.
By fixing this bug, I didn't have the errors displayed anymore. What I mean by this is not that there is a simple solution to your problem, but that maybe like me, you have a silent bug that hides and causes these errors!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not a good way to "solve" a problem. 

The Composition API helps greatly with this issue. There does not seem to be a clear path to deal with the problem in the Options API.

Comment: @iknowmagic I found the bug I had. I had put an enum in a *.d.ts file and I was using this enum in the file that gave me the same error as you. The problem is that an enum can't be in a *.d.ts file because it is not compiled in JS afterwards and you lose the enum's value. 
By fixing this bug, I didn't have the errors displayed anymore. What I mean by this is not that there is a simple solution to your problem, but that maybe like me, you have a silent bug that hides and causes these errors!

Answer (score 0):

The Composition API helps greatly with this issue. There does not seem to be a clear path to deal with the problem in the Options API.

One way to deal with the issue in the Options API:

Create a MyComponent.d.ts file that corresponds to the component that you are working with and add the following in that file:

```
declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    myTroublesomeVariable: boolean // change here
  }
}
```

Comment: Today I started running in the same problem with Composition API setup.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.

Couldn't find a solution after inspecting VSCode/TS and Volar.

Created tiny reproduction (wanted to post it in Discord):

```
<template>
  <input v-model="email" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const email = ref('')
</script>
```

After I saved this file as `Test.vue` the error in other files disappeared. Sorry, but I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

Use `defineComponent` instead of `export default class ParentSupervise extends Vue`.
Write like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ book.title }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { reactive, ref, defineComponent } from "vue";

interface Book {
  title: string;
}
const HelloWorld = defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      boardFields: "燕儿",
    };
  },
  setup() {
    let name = ref("燕");
    const book = reactive({ title: "Vue 3 Guide" }) as Book;
    debugger;
    console.log("name :>> ", name);
    console.log("book :>> ", book);
    // 暴露给 template
    return {
      book,
      name,
    };
  },
});
export default HelloWorld;
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped lang="scss"></style>
```

Comment: No, the SFC syntax is different : v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html If you use this synthax, you have not the defineComponent , the keys: props, data, components... You can use the vuejs2 synthax in vuejs3 TS component.

Comment: you mean this document？https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html

Comment: yes this is the link I shared, but it was not detected by stackoverflow.

Answer (score -2):

You are missing `setup` within `<script lang="ts">` so it should be:

`<script setup lang="ts">`

From the docs:

> When using `<script setup>`, any top-level bindings (including variables, function declarations, and imports) declared inside  are directly usable in the template (...)

https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#top-level-bindings-are-exposed-to-template

Comment: No, the SFC syntax is different : https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html  

If you use this synthax, you have not the defineComponent , the keys: props, data, components... You can use the vuejs2 synthax in vuejs3 TS component.

Comment: Only applies to the composition API. <script setup ... is a special way to write the code.